# EntityUtils .consume returning IOException

Tags: java, ioexception

In my program I am making a call to EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity()). This is throwing an IOException in code, whereas a call to EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) is working perfectly fine. Any ideas on what the issue might be? Or any suggestions to fix the IOException?

```
    if(status >= 200 && status < 300) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (httpEntity != null) {
           if(httpEntity.getContentLength() > Constants.HTTP.MAX_APP_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity too large.");                            
            }
        result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,"UTF-8");
        EntityUtils.consume(httpEntity);                
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Apache HttpCore, but I know in Servlets you can't read the date twice from an HttpServletRequest.  Its using a buffer, and once the buffer is at the end, if you try to read it twice, you get an IOException because the buffer is now empty.